# How to receive any information from Windows Sandbox when run from terminal or script

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-sandbox

I'm working on automating an end-to-end testing process for my desktop app.

I have prepared a script that opens the sandbox, installs all dependencies, runs tests and everything, but after testing is done, my script doesn't know when to terminate the task, as sandbox process is not sending any information back to the host.

Even when If I shut down a remote machine, it doesn't terminate my process on the host as there is a popup that says "Windows Sandbox is shutting down and will be closed" and requires me to click OK button manually

My question is - Is there a way to communicate somehow with the sandbox, to send any signal back, so that I can force shutdown it when tests are done OR is there a way to close the sandbox without this popup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce something like pubsub to the testing chain.

You could add a python Demon to the sandbox configuration that ends the process in question, upon receiving a message from something like Redis or the host service running the test.